# SQL meet conditions based on max value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have to get the player_id and the game_code of the game the user played the most. For each player list the game_code he played the most (not all games he played)

Rules: player_id is unique, and the player could have played multiple games (I want to find out which game he played the most).

I tried with max but I just got lost in trying out.

Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cf0f/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want this

```
SELECT t.player_id, t.game_code, t.minutes_played
FROM (
      SELECT player_id, MAX(minutes_played) as maxi
      FROM play_table
      WHERE game_code in ('123','124','125','126','129')
      GROUP BY player_id
) as m
INNER JOIN play_table as t
  ON t.player_id = m.player_id and 
     t.minutes_played = m.maxi
```

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cf0f/39)

Comment: Sounds really good! I have to leave my PC now but I will try it first thing in the morning and upvote the solution if it works! 
Thank you for the ULTRA fast suggestion!!!
Cheers

Comment: As I posted in the other suggestion I would like to get just the game_codes for each user that he played the most. Sorry if my description was not clear enough!

Comment: can I ask you for the explanation, why was this INNER JOIN needed?

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is on the right track, but you need to group by player_id in the subquery, assuming you want all of them:

```
SELECT m.player_id, pt.game_code, pt.minutes_played
FROM (
    SELECT player_id, max(minutes_played) as maxi
    FROM play_table
    GROUP BY player_id
) as m
INNER JOIN play_table pt
ON  m.player_id = pt.player_id
AND pt.minutes_played = m.maxi;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I get too much results. I need to get the player_id and the game_code but just for the one game he played the most. For example player_id 1 should only have game_code 125 because he played that game the most. For player_id 2 it should be just game_code 124 and so on... thanks for your help!!